# How to resolve index.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setWallpaper' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello All I'm new to react native and started with wallpaper app. I'm using [react-native-wallpaper-manager](https://github.com/ramonrpa/react-native-wallpaper-manager) to built an App and
I'm getting following error:

> index.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setWallpaper' of undefined

index.js

```
var  NativeModules = require('react-native');
var Image  = require('react-native');

module.exports = {
setWallpaper: (source,callback = (res)=>{
    console.log(res);
}) =>{
    NativeModules.WallPaperManager.setWallpaper(Image.resolveAssetSource(source),callback);
 }
 } ;
```

App.js

```
 WallPaperManager.setWallpaper({uri: 'img_link', screen: 'both/home/lockscreen'}, (res)=> console.log(res));
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm had the same issue.
I have tried these libraries as well , all gettings the same error

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-manage-wallpaper

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wallpaper-enhanced

Try this one instead 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-manage-wallpaper/v/1.1.2

Comment: Link-only answers should be considered as comments